# Python multiprocessing initialising the Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a large read-only object that I would like the child processes to use but unfortunately this object cannot be pickled. Given that it's read-only I thought about declaring it as a global and then using an initializing function in the Pool where I perform the necessary copying. My code is something like:

```
def f(processes, args):

    global pool   
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes,setGlobal,[args])

def setGlobal(args):

    # global object to be used by the child processes... 
    global obj
    obj = copy.deepcopy(args)
```

The function setGlobal performs the initialization. My first question concerns the arguments to setGlobal (which are passed as a list). Do these need to be pickle-able? The errors I'm getting seem to suggest that they do. If so, how can I make the unpickle-able read-only object visible to my child processes?

Comment: What kind of object this is? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I've been coming up against the same problem. If `obj` isn't pickleable, you can't use `multiprocessing`. You can try the `pathos` multiprocessing package, but its dependencies are very annoying on Windows.

Comment: The object is returned by an external lib. It's not pickle-able. I'm running Python 2.7.1 on Windows, using Eclipse as my dev environment.